# Need Help to Realize a Function in a Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, text-mining

I need to make a function that can check a given word and return another word. For example, if the input is "a1", the function will check for this word in the dictionary and return "a".

I know how to code it if it is just a single input word per category using a simple if-else, but I'm still confused if a category has more than 3 words. And I plan to have a lot of data in this dictionary. So a simple if-else would need a lot of code to be written.

[image: this is how the dictionary visualized]

this is the example for the input & output that i want:

Input : a2 Output : a

 Input : b3 Output : b

Comment: can you provide input/output desired , and what did you try

Comment: Do you need to use dictionary? You can simply do `x[0]` if `x= 'a3'`

Comment: For string processing take a look at `regular expressions` , a sub-language that is implemented in python. It is somewhat terse but there are good explanation to be found for free and also free test pages that allow you to learn it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you meant the Python term 'dictionary' or were just referring to a dictionary as storage for permissible words (could be a list, tuple, dict).

Comment: If all of your words end in a single digit you could just strip that with slicing notation. Strings (like lists) can be `sliced` with this syntax   a[:10] (first 10 characters), a[10:] all characters after the first 10, a[:-1] all characters up to the last one , a[-3:] the last three characters , a[:-5] all characters but the last 5

Comment: @BenyGj i did try to build a "lemmatizer" for traditional language. and i cant find anything refer to that language. so i must build it from scratch. and i think the simplest way to do is make some dictionary like the table i mentioned before and the function just to check the input words is available in words column or not. is available than return the return words. bcs is to hard to make some rule for that

Answer (score 1):

If you really just need to strip a single digit number on the end (per your example):

```
words=['a1','a2','a3','a4','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2','d1']

realwords= set()   # empty set, like a list, but can only have each item once, no duplication

for w in words:
    realwords.add(w[:-1])

print(realwords)
```

{'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'}

If you have a more complex problem than single digits, please append it to your question. There are many ways to solve such problems in Python. In the above example I used the concept of the `set`, which can be very powerful to ensure that no duplication happens. You can convert the set back to a list easily `b=list(a)`

Comment: oh im sorry i think i not clear enoug. i mean some input word is random and it can be anything except number. and the function is checking input word is available in dictionary like i mentioned in before. if the input words was found in words column of dictionary then the function will return the return word as a result

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a list of words and you want to replace a certain word with another word? In many programming languages I think you would use a switch-case statement for something like this. This can be implemented in Python by using a dict:

```
switch = {
    "a1" : "a",
    "a2" : "a",
    "a3" : "a",
    "a4" : "a",
    "b1" : "b",
    "b2" : "b",
    "b3" : "b",
    "c1" : "c",
    "c2" : "c",
    "c3" : "c",
    "d1" : "d",
    "d2" : "d"
}
test_word = "d1"
answer = switch[test_word]
print(answer) #d
```

The bracket notation of [ ] used on a dict looks in the dict for a key matching the value within the brackets. It returns the corresponding value of that key in the dictionary. If it is not found it will raise a KeyError.

If you want to return a different value in the case that the key is not found, then you can use .get instead, like so:

```
switch.get(test_word, "not found")
```

Comment: okay thanks for the answer, but i think i'll make a big dictionary for it so make a switch maybe will need a lot of effort. but you right what i need is replace input word with return word. is it possible to make function do loop checking over the "word" column and return the "return word"? and i forget, i will very happy if i can make the dictionary looks like the table i mentioned before

Comment: You won't need to make a loop to check each word, the bracket notation of [ ] does that for you.

Comment: How are you going to create the dict? Rather than typing it all in manually, if possible, it would be a good idea to make a script to create the dictionary for you?